# Question related to proof of: For variable separable solutions to the Schrodinger equation to be normalizable, the separation constant must be real

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I need to prove: For variable separable solutions to the Schrodinger equation to be normalizable, the separation constant must be real.

This can be proven as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x)\phi(t)|^2 dx\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x)e^{-ikt/\hbar}|^2 dx\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x)e^{-i(k_R + ik_I)t/\hbar}|^2 dx\\
& = e^{2k_It/\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x)|^2 dx\\ 
\end{align}
The second factor (integral) is independent of $t$ and therefore for the product to be a finite non-zero constant, the first factor should also be independent of time, which is possible iff $k_I = 0$ (i.e., iff $k \in \mathbb{R}$). (QED)

(Here $k = k_R + i k_I$ (where $k_R$ and $k_I$ are real numbers) is the separation constant and exp(constant of integration) from $\phi(t)$ has been absorbed in $\psi(x)$. Also, please note that I am using $k$ instead of $E$ to denote the separation constant.)

BUT I have not been successful in trying to prove the same thing using Equation 1.26, Section 1.4, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics (2nd Ed) (by David Griffiths). The equation I am referring to, is:

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx = \frac{i\hbar}{2m}(\Psi^*\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}-\Psi\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x})|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$
(if the potential energy function is real)

If I replace $\Psi(x,t)$ by $\psi(x)\phi(t)$ in the above equation, I get:

$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} |\phi(t)|^2 (\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x})|_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \frac{i\hbar}{2m} e^{2k_It/\hbar} (\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial x})|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$

Now, shouldn't $\psi$ go to zero as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$, for the wave-function to be normalizable? (Griffiths says, just below equation 1.26, that "... $\Psi(x,t)$ must go to zero as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$ - otherwise, the wave-function would not be normalizable." Here, wouldn't this mean that $\psi(x)$ must go to zero as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$?) If it does go to zero, then the RHS would be zero irrespective of whether $|\phi(t)|^2$ is a constant or not, i.e., irrespective of whether the separation constant is real or not.

Am I missing something here?

Could it be possible that $\psi(x)$ does not go to zero when $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$ for $k \in \mathbb{C \setminus R}$?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The part you are referring to, is probably the one with $k_I$. The exponent is a real number. I have already removed the imaginary part.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero. Please check it again. I have added the clarification.

Comment: $|exp(-ikt)|^2=1$ . Either "k" is real or imaginary.

Comment: @baponkar I am assuming that $k$ is a general complex number $k_R+ik_I$ where  $k_R$ and $k_I$ are real. So, $-ik = -i(k_R+ik_I) = -ik_R+k_I$.

Comment: $exp(-ikt)=exp(-ik_R t).exp(k_I t)$;$exp(ikt)=exp(ik_R t).exp(-k_I t)$.so |exp(-ik t)|^2=1.just algebra

Comment: @baponkar you're doing it wrong. For complex conjugate you need to flip the signs of both $i$s, so for complex $k$, $|\exp(-ikt)|^2 = \exp(2k_It)$.

Comment: $[exp(-ik)]^* = exp(ik^*)$ ; where $k^*=k_R-i k_I$!

Comment: @baponkar Very good. $ik^* = ik_R + i (-ik_I) = ik_R + k_I$. :)

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing is that what your last equation is actually proving is that the sufficient condition for the normalization to be constant is for the net [probability current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current) through the boundaries (at $\pm\infty$) to be zero.

Now, strictly speaking, even if $k_I\neq0$ the wave function is still normalizable - doing the normalization will just cancel the factor of $\exp(k_It)$, removing it from your wave function. Say your original un-normalized wave function is $\Psi$ define 
$$\Psi_N = \frac{\Psi}{\sqrt{\int |\Psi|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}} \tag1$$
and watch it vanish.

That's just a nitpick of terminology, though. The real problem is not that $\Psi$ isn't normalizable, it's that it fails an unstated boundary condition: $\Psi$ has to be finite for $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$. That boundary condition is less strict than requiring that $\Psi$ be normalized (note: not normalizable, normalized) but it is sufficient to do the job.

There is, of course, another route you can take. You can focus on the $x$ equation instead of the $t$ one:
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \psi'' + V(x)\psi = k \psi. \tag2$$
Take the complex conjugate of (2) and call it (3). Multiply (2) by $\psi^*$ and (3) by $\psi$ then integrate both sides over all $x$. Now subtract the pairs of equations, and manipulate the integrals using integration by parts to leave only surface terms (i.e. something of the form $[\ldots]_{x=-\infty}^\infty$). The right hand side will be $(k - k^*) \int |\psi|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x$. Normalizability requires the left hand side of the equation to vanish. The right hand side can only vanish if $k=k^*$, q.e.d.

This last version is an example of how to prove that a Hermitian operator's eigenvalues are real.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. May I ask you another question: how exactly is normalizability defined? (And what exactly is a normalizable wavefunction?) Also, this is actually related to a problem in Introduction to Quantum Mechanics (2nd Ed) (by David Griffiths) - Problem 2.1 asks the reader to prove that "For _normalizable_ solutions, the separation constant must be real."

Comment: @AB Applying equation (1) is called normalizing a wave function. So, a normalizable wave function is one that we can apply (1) to without any divide by zero of infinity problems. The word 'normalizable' literally means, "Able to be normalized". I suspect that Griffiths is just being sloppy with his usage.

Comment: 1) Would it be more appropriate to say "... the sufficient condition for _the probability that the particle exists (or the probability of finding the particle between $x \to -\infty$ and $x \to +\infty$)_ to be constant is for the net probability current through the boundaries to be zero." Also, isn't this condition necessary as well? And 2) Why is '$\Psi$ has to be finite for $t \to \pm \infty$' a boundary condition? What physical restriction does it convey? Is it related to ensuring the finite-ness of $|\Psi|^2$ for all $x$ and $t$?

Comment: And 3) Can I say "The separation constant must real so that $\Psi$ satisfies the boundary condition that '$\Psi$ has to be finite for $t \to \pm \infty$' **or** so that $\Psi$ is normalizable for all values of $t$ (as $\Psi_N$ takes the form of $\infty/\infty$ and $0/0$ for $t \to \pm \infty$ (or in the other order, depending on whether $k_I$ is positive or negative))"

Comment: @AB "Can I say..." You can say anything, but you'll want to discuss with your TA and/or professor what they'll accept. 
1) Be careful, there. IIRC, the full logic is that for $H$ to be Hermitian the probability flux on the boundaries has to vanish, and $H$ being hermitian implies the real constant. If you satisfy that condition and $H$ isn't Hermitian, no dice.

Comment: @AB 2) $|\Psi|^2$ doesn't have to be finite for all $x$ and $t$. Consider $\exp(-|x|) / |x|^{1/3}$. It's not finite at $x=0$, but otherwise quite well behaved. It's more accurate to say that $\int_a^b |\Psi|^2\, \mathrm{d}x$ has to be finite for any finite interval $a,b\in(-\infty,\infty)$, and normalizability requires that you allow the infinite interval, too. The reason I stated it as $\Psi$ being finite is that, in your example, $\Psi$ was infinite anywhere $\psi\neq0$. The reason why can be described in terms of probability or energy, depending on formalism.

Comment: The normalized wave-function ($\Psi_N$) obtained using equation (1), from a variable-separable wavefunction calculated using a non-real separation constant, does not satisfy the corresponding time-dependent Schrodinger equation. Would it still be considered the normalized form of the variable-separable wave-function? (I'm actually not taking a course on it right now, otherwise I would've discussed it with my TA. I'm apologize for bothering you with such trivial questions.)

Comment: @AB Good point. But, then, I'm pretty sure you can show that non-real $k$ causes the spatial part of the wave function to fail the $\psi\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$, so it's kinda moot. (note: "pretty sure" means I don't actually know how, at the moment).